# javascript variables, What does var x = a = {} do?

Tags: javascript, variables, syntax

I see in jQuery something like this:

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {}
```

Why is this being done? Isn't this the same thing just saying jQuery.prototype = {}? I'm not sure I understand what Resig is accomplishing here.

Answer (score 13):

The same as:

```
jQuery.prototype = {}
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype
```

In my opinion having all in one line makes more clear that your assigning the same value to both variables

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent to:

```
jQuery.prototype = {}
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype
```

In other words jQuery.fn and jQuery.prototype both point to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

The statement `x = a = {}` means that `{}` is assigned to `a` that is assigned to `x`. So it’s equal to `a = {}; x = a`.

Comment: Yes but in his example jQuery.fn is already the same entity as jQuery as jQuery.prototype.  The fn is just a shortcut for prototype.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to know is that in javascript, every expression has a return value, regardless of if it has any side effects (of assignment)

From right to left, you have the following statements:

```
(jQuery.fn = (jQuery.prototype = ({})))
```

Evaluating the first part gives an empty object: {}:

```
(jQuery.fn = (jQuery.prototype = {}))
```

The second statement executes and sets jQuery.prototype to {}, and it evaluates to jQuery.prototype, giving the second part:

```
(jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype)
```

which sets jQuery.fn to jQuery.prototype, which then evaluates to:

```
jQuery.fn
```

which does nothing.

Comment: Evaluating the first part yields an empty object (not an 'array')--that can be an important distinction.

Comment: Actually is jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype, not jQuery.fn = {}, as jQuery.fn and jQuery.prototype are supposed to be aliased.

Comment: in javascript land aren't arrays/tables/objects the same thing? It's been a while. Regardless, I've updated my answer.

Comment: They are essentially the same, but arrays have special behavior for numeric properties (basically, length gets adjusted automatically when you assign to a numeric index that doesn't exist). Arrays also have a separate prototype, which is where they get slice, map, sort, etc.