# What does var prime = num != 1; mean?

Tags: javascript

I know this is similar to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100159/javascript-variables-what-does-var-x-a-do), but the variable `prime` is supposed to be any number other than `1`, and it looks to me like it would be assigned the boolean value of `num != 1`.  Can anyone tell me what this line of code is actually doing?

**Here's the code where it's being used**

```
function isPrime( num ) { 
  var prime = num != 1; // Everything but 1 can be prime 
  for ( var i = 2; i < num; i++ ) { 
    if ( num % i == 0 ) { 
      prime = false; 
      break; 
    } 
  } 
  return prime; 
}
```

**EDIT:**
I assume that this line does something like this:

```
if( num != 1) {
    prime = num;
}
```

But I still want to know *why* or *how* this line of code does this.

Comment: Basically `prime` is a boolean like you thought, and `num` is the number you are checking to see if it's prime.

Comment: Ah, I see it now.  I thought that prime was the holder of a number, not a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you were thinking correctly, the statement `var prime = num != 1;` assigns the result of the boolean expression `(num != 1)` to the variable `prime`. This special case is included in kind of every prime checking code because `1` itself is not a prime number.

Your algorithm could be even faster if you only checked for divisors up to the square root of the input value. You can read about this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) and may notice that it's far more efficient to check if `num > i*i` than `sqrt(num) > i`.

Additionally the algorithm you have could still return wrong values if you feed it negative or zero values.

Comment: Actually, the loop will be skipped if `num == 1`. The loop starts with `i = 2` and 2 is **NOT** less than 1.  So... it's not bad for performance, it's just bad for readability.

Comment: this is true. My bad I was kind of confused ;) I adapted my answer. However it is still bad to loop up to the number itself when it would be enough to check up to the square root of the number to check.

Answer (score 2):

In other words:

If num == 1, set *prime* to false and skip the loop.

Otherwise, enter the loop and use the standard logic to determine the value of *prime*.

This is done because the standard logic (inside the loop) will not work on the number 1.

Therefore, as pst says, you check for the edge case outside the loop.

This helps keep the logic clean inside the loop.

---

To make it more readable (and correct for all values) I would re-write it like this:

```
function isPrime( num ) { 

    if (num <= 1) {
        return false;
    }

    for ( var i = 2; i < num; i++ ) { 
        if ( num % i == 0 ) { 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 

    return true; 
}
```

You could also exit the loop once i is greater than `num / 2` to make it more efficient.

Comment: @s1lence - Actually, it will skip the loop because _i_ starts at 2, which is **NOT** less than 1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

[1 is not a prime number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Primality_of_one)

That is an edge-case check because `for(i = 2;..)` (below) "skips" 1: because the loop never runs, `prime` is only set once to `false` (which is the evaluation of `i != 1`, when `i = 1`).

However, I find it confusing and would have used:

```
if (i <= 1) {
  return false;
} else {
  // other stuff
}
```

Comment: I realize 1 isn't prime.  My question is "what does this line of code do?"

Comment: @NickG. I forget that not everyone understands that `x op y` is just an expression in JavaScript (and expressions evaluate to values which can be assigned to variables, etc.) :-/

Comment: Agreed that your code is more readable.  This is why you should almost always (in my opinion) choose to write your code in the most readable fashion possible.  Otherwise people read your code, scratch their head, create questions on StackOverflow, and waste time that could be spent on maintainence!

Answer (score 1):

The point of that line of code is to achieve two goals in one:

- Firstly, they need to create a boolean variable
- Second, they need to check if the number is 1, then it's not prime

They are just doing both at the same time.